# Azure Mobile Services vs Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I have just started using Web API to create REST based services to be used within my MVC apps, which I am calling a lot from client side code.  Now I have noticed Azure Mobile Services provides an alternative and simple way to interact with your database from client side code.  What is the advantage (if any) of using Azure Mobile Services over Web API?

Answer (score 7):

1. It is really easy to get started from scratch. If you have no idea, or maybe no inclination or time to create a Web API project, a Database, configure CORS, scaffold up some client access scripts etc then Azure Mobile Services is great.
2. Features such as dynamic DB schema, OAuth (and security baked into the DB) and push notifications out of the box, with OKish documentation.
3. Native libraries to access your services from Android, IOS and Windows Mobile & Win 8 Store.
4. Code server scripts in JS (maybe an advantage, if you're not a C# dev).

That said, if you're already up and running in Web API, then I don't think there is any compelling reason for you to change. You'll almost certainly hit limitations and you can access other Azure services including Mobile if you need a specific feature anyway.

Comment: Actually, that's strange for me that none has voted that answer before. That's pretty unlear for (including Web API-ish) .NET developers, why Azure would be needed (becides, just hosting environment). I still can not catch it fully.

Comment: Agat, AZM (Azure Mobile Services, which this question is specifically related to) is a pretty small subset of Azure. Azure includes Web Sites and databases, media capabilities, service bus and much more. Azure (and other Cloud providers) are great if you need more than "just hosting" for scalability and other traditionally high cost upfront capabilities.